# WSO2 BPS Shared HTTP Cookies

Tags: cookies, wso2, bpel

Consider the scenario where we need to orchestrate WSO2 Carbon administration services: **AuthenticationAdmin** and **UserAdmin** (through **WSO2 BPS BPEL Process**). The **AuthenticationAdmin** service for authenticated users returns **JSESSIONID** cookie that shall be used (injected in the HTTP requests) in the subsequent calls (*listUsers()* in the **UserAdmin** for example). However it seems that the HTTP cookie is **not shared** and used for the web services in the same domain:

```
http://localhost:9443/services/AuthenticationAdmin
http://localhost:9443/services/UserAdmin
```

Any opinions or solutions to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that WSO2 BPS currently can only access (get/set) the SOAP headers of a message (not the HTTP headers) when the service binding is SOAP. So you can use an ESB in front of the BPS, so that the cookie returned from carbon can be copied from HTTP header to a custom SOAP header. Then you'll be able to access it via the BPS and can be stored as a variable. Later BPS can do admin calls with this cookie in the SOAP header and ESB can copy it to the HTTP header. You can read more about HTTP header accessing in Apache ODE/WSO2 BPS in [this](http://old.nabble.com/HTTP-Header-Issues-td20485170.html) thread.

Comment: We are working on solution s.t. a BPEL process can invoke a carbon administrative process via BasicAuth and the user-name and password can be configured in the BPEL artifact itself. So this solution will provide a way to invoke carbon administrative services without fronting an ESB. You can track the progress of this work from https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-13111

Comment: Hi Denis, thanks for your response. The Apache ODE documentation says that they are handling wire headers through BPEL extension. So, when I switch to HTTPS service endpoints (login and listUsers), why this BPEL copy operation doesn't exchange the JSESSIONID cookie:`<bpel:copy>
                <bpel:from variable="loginResponse" header="Set-Cookie"/>
                <bpel:to variable="listUsersRequest" header="Cookie"/>
            </bpel:copy>`

Comment: I think its mentioned in the thread I posted above.. "The header attribute of an assignment sets a header on the abstract representation of the message. The representation used to send this message depends on the service binding. SOAP binding -> SOAP header ; HTTP binding -> HTTP header (and this is a specific case where binding and transport are the same) 
So if the service you're invoking uses a SOAP-binding, don't expect the HTTP header to be set."

Comment: Yes, I tried with HTTP binding and the JSESSIOND cookie is not set using the above copy procedure (Set-Cookie ->Cookie).